# The view is ill formated. Please remove it

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, list, powershell, list-view

I tried to access list settings on SharePoint 2010 site, and got information that "An unexpected error has occurred". I checked the logs and most likely there is something wrong with  views on my list. Error message said: "The view is ill formated. Please remove it". 
I used powershell, did a bit of wandering and discovered broken view. It's title and id equals null.

[image]

How do I delete this view? List.Views.Delete won't work because it requires ID which is null.

Comment: I found this broken view in sql. Has anyone any experience in deleting items through sql query? Probably not supported, but will it break anything?

Comment: try sharepoint manager. avoid sql modifications

Comment: How about creating new list and migrating content to the new list?

Comment: are all the views corrupted or only one? can you create new view using pwoershell and make it default?

Comment: List works fine, I can access all the data. The problem occurs while I try accessing list settings. I suppose SharePoint tries geting all views by calling list.views and getting exception that id is null in result displaying error.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you using SharePoint Designer, find and click the relevant list in the Lists and Libraries Tab, and find the relevant view under Views section, then delete it.

[image]

Comment: Tried it. Designer shows erorr when trying to access this list